# Coverting a text file into csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file like this:

```
Name: John Sanj
Age: 23
Gender: Male
```

I want to covert it in csv like this:

```
Name,Age,Gender
John Sanj,23,Male
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import os
filepath=os.path.normpath('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\new\\ac.txt')
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Name', 'Age','Gender'))
        for line in f:
            x=line.split(':')
            x[-1]=x[-1].strip()
            b=x[1]
            writer.writerow(b)
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
Name,Age,Gender

J,o,h,n, ,S,a,n,j

2,3

M,a,l,e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the strings from each line to `writerow` (instead of all the lines), and strings being iterable, get splitted into their constituent characters.

You should **read** all the lines at once, **strip** the newline character, **split** on `': '` (notice the trailing space), and then **transpose**.

Here:

```
with open(filepath) as f, open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    rows = zip(*[line.rstrip().split(': ') for line in f])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks,but I wiil be reading a lot of text files and convert them into a single csv file.I want to display the key(Name,Age,Gender) only once.

Comment: Then you can write the header (i.e. first line) once, and always discard the header from the other files since the header is the same.

Comment: How to discard the header?